# Conjugate Hyperpriors

Tags: bayesian, prior, hierarchical-bayesian, conjugate-prior

I heard it was possible to have a Bayesian model with likelihood, prior and hyperprior that has a posterior of closed form, by choosing a conjugate prior and conjugate hyperprior. But I struggle to imagine how that would work, except for models where likelihood and prior are the same.

E.g. when I have a Normal-Normal model, a Normal hyperprior would probably result in a Normal posterior. But how would that work for other distributions? For example, could a Dirichlet prior and Multinomial likelihood be enhanced with a conjugate hyperprior?

Comment: Where did you hear this? Link or reference?

Comment: My professor told me, but I could not reach her lately..

Comment: I am also interested in seing an example of this. The current wikipedia page on hyperpriors mentions that the conjugate form exists, but gives no examples. The reference it gives is to the book; Bernardo, J. M.; Smith, A. F. M. (2000). Bayesian Theory, as well as; Ntzoufras, Ioannis (2009). "Bayesian Hierarchical Models".